# Problem on loading maps from the apk

Tags: android, dictionary

i have created an app with maps.i have followed every step as i have found from the web,i have got the key and the app is working excellent on the emulator and i can see the maps.But as i load the singned apk to my mobile the map is not showing...:(..any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this (assuming the that keytool is in your path):

Type

**keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias release_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000**

```
You should see the following prompts:
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  FirstName Surname
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  FirstName Surname
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  FirstName Surname
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  YourTown
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  YourTown
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  UK
Is CN=FirstName Surname, OU=FirstName Surname, O=FirstName Surname, L=YourTown, ST=YourTown, C=UK c
orrect?
  [no]:  yes

Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA1withRSA) with
 a validity of 10,000 days
        for: CN=FirstName Surname, OU=FirstName Surname, O=FirstName Surname, L=YourTown, ST=Lond
on, C=UK
Enter key password for <release_alias>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
[Storing my-release-key.keystore]
```

This keystore will be in the the directory where you ran the keytool command from, in my case it was in C:\users\FirstName

Now to view the generated MD5 fingerprint, type:

**keytool -list -alias release_alias -keystore c:\users\FirstName\my-release-key.keystore**

You will see:

```
Enter keystore password:
release_alias, 08-Sep-2010, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**

    (** is substituted for my private information, you should see hex values)
```

This is your new MD5 generated from the RELEASE key, submit this to the Google API key page and you will get back:

```
Thank you for signing up for an Android Maps API key!
Your key is:
1234567891bcdefg1234567891bcdefg (or whatever yours is)
This key is good for all apps signed with your certificate whose fingerprint is:
**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**
```

Put that key in your XML

Comment: thats what i m doing but it s not working..i dont think that its wron g but i cant understand where it stacks

Comment: i have done the same thing and i can only see grey background and my icon on the map..

Comment: Have you now got two different keys back from Google then? (One for debug and one for signed applications)

Comment: yes.when i use the debug the app is loading the maps when i use my device as emulator but not in the dalvik emulator.then,i change to the signed key and the map is not loading on the device

Comment: When you get the Google API key based upon the MD5 that came from your release MD5 certificate. You need to edit your XML to include this key. Then you rebuild the project and finally you sign the APK with your release key (not to be confused with the Google API key) from your release keystore. In Eclipse you do this by Export/ Export Android Application, and pointing the resulting popup at your release keystore (not the debug one). Do you do all this in that order?

Comment: ok,i have done a silly mistake.i was right from the beginning but i was stacked!thanks both for your answers mates!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a key for signing your aplication. 
Than for this key of yours you need to go tru all the steps, just as you did with the emulator autogenerated one.

When you sign your application from eclipse, you are asked if you want to create a key, make one and remember where you stored it.

Then go to C:\Program Files\Java\\bin"  and run the following command:
from a command window

> keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\YourCreatedKey" -storepass android -keypass android

Copy the MD5 certificate fingerprint and navigate your web browser to: http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html. Follow the instructions on the page to complete the application and obtain the Google Maps key.

Use the obtain key in your mapView control in your xml layout.

Comment: do you have any tutorial on that please?

Comment: i have done this http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/android/maps-api-signup.html and i have got my Certificate fingerprint (MD5)

Comment: i have done this but it says that password is in correct.where should i write the pass in the cmd?

Comment: ok,my query was silly..i got a new md5,i changed it in my xml file but i cant load maps again...i really cannot understand where i m wrong guys

Comment: No, this answer is wrong. You have used the the alias for the debugkey. You need to use the alias for the release key that you created with the keytool -genkey command

Comment: It's not the MD5 that you put in the xml, it's the Google API key that is returned from the site when you submit the MD5 to Google. The MD5 should be generated from a release key that you previously generated using the keytool. The debug key only works in the emulator

Comment: could you please write the new command line?i m confused trying this way more that 5 times...